# Why are emails sent successfully from my Django project using the Gmail SMTP server on localhost but not on AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, smtp

I use the Gmail SMTP server for my Django project, which I have deployed on AWS. The emails are sent and work locally on localhost, but they are not working from AWS. I have 2 step verification enabled on Gmail and generated app password which I use in two different .env files, one locally and one in the cloud. I use the same password (if that matters).

Additionally, I have added port 587 to the inbound rules of the Security Groups but still not working.

[image]